SCP hangs during GitLab CI pipeline run
I want to use SCP to deploy artifacts from a build server to a webserver.
I am using GitLab CI.
In the gitlab-ci.yaml file, if I include a stage to SCP files between the servers, as in this simple example...
deploy_job:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - 'scp -r C:\example\ administrator@ipv4ofwebserver:C:\example\'

... then the SCP command hangs until timeout during the pipeline run.
Running the same command manually on the build server...
> scp -r C:\example\ administrator@ipv4ofwebserver:C:\example\

... works without a hitch. So it is not an issue with SCP/OpenSSH or the command syntax.
I seem to be missing something with regards to the gitlab-runner, as this is the warning I receive upon timeout (when the SCP job times out):

**WARNING: Failed to terminate process: 1 error occurred: Failed to attach the runner process to the console of its parent process: The handle is invalid.

All other jobs prior to the SCP job are picked up and executed by the gitlab-runner. This timeout error only occurs when a job includes an SSH/SCP command.

can you share the pipeline ? I mean the pipeline alraedy picked up the runner or not ?

Yes the runner picks up all jobs in the pipeline before this job. It's specifically jobs that involve an scp/ssh command which have this issue.

Failed to attach the runner process to the console of its parent process: The handle is invalid. I think the runner is not being attached into the pipeline

@ThanhNguyenVan
The runner is successfully executing several jobs in the pipeline before the SCP job. So it is interacting properly with the pipeline - just not with the SCP job.
